# Is there a way to evaluate the number of leaves needed by a B+ tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, b-tree

If I have t = #tuples (or #records) and the only other info I can exploit is the fanout F of my B+ tree, is there a way to get how many leaves (#blocks for the leaves) the tree will need ? Assuming the tree must be balanced and so keeping the most information in the least space possible.

Example: t = 40K, F = 40  ==> depth = log_40(40K) = 3 , #leaves = ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [B+ tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree) the actual records are referenced from within the leaves. The internal nodes on the other hand don't reference records directly, but define ranges for key values in order to traverse through the tree to the leaf(block) that finally has the key values of the records of interest.

Another property of B+ trees is that the number of children of an internal node not only has an upper bound (i.e. the fanout *F*) but also a lower bound: *F/2*. (I'm ignoring that the root is exempted from this lower-bound rule). This 1/2 coefficient is the fill factor (0.5).

The number of leaf-blocks (*L*) is bound by the number of records (*t*) and the fanout (*F*), but not by the way the tree is (un)balanced. In the best, minimal case we have:

*min(L) = ⌈ t / F⌉*

In the worst, maximal case we have:

*max(L) = ⌈ 2t / F⌉*

If you have a different fill factor (*c* >= 0.5), then the worst case is:

*max(L) = ⌈ t / cF⌉*

Be aware that increasing the fill factor reduces used space, but increases time overhead when inserting records. When the fill factor would be close to 1, space usage is kept at the bare minimum, but updates will be slow.

Comment: I see.. Could you also tell me how a Filling Factor f would affect this evaluation? 
For instance, having f = 50% (I think this means that every leaf block must be filled by the 50% of its size, correct?)

Comment: The fill factor is indeed that (for internal and leaf blocks), and must be at least 50% for B+ trees. If you increase it, *L* decreases. I added this in my answer just now.

Comment: Thanks a lot @trincot !! Precise and concise :)

Comment: Sorry but I got another doubt. What's the difference between the depth of the tree and the levels of the tree? From my understandings essentially level = depth + 1 where depth = #arcs from leaf to root.
And how much a general lookup in a B+-tree costs? Reading lectures on Database 2 it's not clear.. sometimes you know the tree levels, sometimes you have the depth but othertimes they're considered synonyms. If I have depth = 3, is it correct to assume that a general lookup costs 3 i/o operations (3 access to reach the leaf)?And what about the level-based cost?

Comment: Indeed, level = depth + 1. A tree with just one block (the root) would have 1 level and 0 depth. When calculating the cost (time complexity) of a look-up, the difference between the two is not important (not significant), as it represents a constant (i.e. 1). We use [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for representing costs, and O(level) = O(depth). You are right about the number of i/o operations. The cost at one level, i.e. at one node would be O(F), but as those are typically fast in-memory operations, some would just take that as a constant cost independent of F.